# Assembler code not working

Tags: assembly, arm

I've been doing a software the last few days with the help of some people from here and now the code is finished but it seems to have some errors since it does not what it's suposed to.

The code is as follows:

```
            add r3,#1
            b .loop_ini

        .add_row:
            add r2,#1
            mov r3,#0
            b .loop_ini



            LDR r2,=0x0019660D
            umull r4,r5,r1,r2   @;RLo,RHi,N,M; r5 contains 32low bits from 
        .while_end:
            mov r0,r2           @;Movemos el resultado del modulo a r0
            pop {r1-r2,pc}          @;restores modified registers and returns

.end
```

Does anyone find any error? I think but don't know for sure that the error may be when inserting the random values into the matrix.

Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could tell us what it is supposed to do and what it does.

Comment: "it does not what it's suposed to." - What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: Hello, It's suposed to generate a random number between 0 and r0-1. This number is first created in random then treated in mod_random to become a number between 0 and r0-1 then this number should retrun to the main and be inserted into the first position of the matrix 0x0 then the program should run until there are no rows or columns to fill. The main problems I had were finding how to insert the number into the matrix and how to change the seed32 which is defined in .data;
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you don't provide much information about the intended functionality of the code I've to take some guesses, but the first thing that catches my eye is:

```
str r6, [r0]
```

As far as I can follow the code, r0 is supposed to be the random value and r6 should be the address where it should be saved to.

You have to swap those two in the `str`, as r0 is now used as the address and r6 as the value to be stored.

You also have to use `strb` instead of `str`, at least it seemed like you want to work with bytes, not full 32bit-words.

I didn't look into it any further, there could be more problems. In general the code does not seem to be written by somebody who is experienced in ARM-assembly it has a lot of room for optimization. TBH, unless you have a GOOD reason to use assembly you should consider to switch to C or another high-level language. A proper compiler will generate better code with less headaches for you.

Comment: Hello, I have just the experience from last year. Unfortunately this is homework that I have to do but they did not provide us with any information just told us what to do and well I'm trying my best.
Thanks for the help right now I will test your answer if I understand:

        str r6, [r0] should become strb r0,[r6] ??

Thanks for the effort I will be back soon telling if worked.
By the way I'm using devkitpro and the insight debugger if not wrong.

Comment: Your response did correct the matrix filling but I still have some weird issues since the matrix is not filling 10x8 but 5x15 :-| And it's being filled by 1 not a random sort between 0 and r0-1 which in this case I set it to be r0=2 so the values should be between 0-1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code is just horribly broken in so many ways. For example, in random you're not loading your seed but the pointer to the seed value, then you never save the seed. The `str` in random is also broken. mod_random also does not do what it's supposed to do (and it will be horribly slow).

Comment: Oh and have any idea how to fix that?? I'm sorry for botherind so much but it's just that I don't know how to do it work and how to make it better. Thanks.

NOW I added the code with few corrections you have been telling me , well the ones I knew how to fix. The program is still not working. :( Thanks.

Comment: Well now I think I found the problem and it's the follwing:
The seed is not being updated so every position of the matrix has the same random number.

Comment: Well thanks for the negatives everyone...